# How to automatically choose related model using field value

Tags: django

Assume, we have model

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    is_a = models.BooleanField()
```

and two models related to this one:

```
class A(models.Model):
    value_1 = models.IntegerField()
    base = models.ForeignKey(BaseModel, related_name='a')

class B(models.Model):
    value_1 = models.IntegerField()
    value_2 = models.IntegerField()
    base = models.ForeignKey(BaseModel, related_name='b')
```

What I need is to refer to A or B depending on is_a property.

For example,

```
base = BaseModel.objects.get(id=1)
if base.is_a:
    obj = A.objects.create(value_1=1, base=base)
else:
    obj = B.objects.create(value_1=1, value_2=2, base=base)
return obj
```

or

```
if base.is_a:
    queryset = base.a.all()
else:
    queryset = base.b.all()
return queryset
```

i.e., every time I have to check the is_a property.

Is there more graceful way?

There are two only related models, A and B, no other ones will appear in the nearest future.

Part of the problem can be solved with django-polymorphic, e.g.:

```
class A(PolymorphicModel):
    ...

class B(A):
    ...
```

This allows to retrieve all A's and B's with one request like `base.b.all()`, but the problem here is that every B creates instance of A, which is unwanted.

I've considered GenericForeignKey as well. As far as I understood it has a number of limitations like "1) You can't use GenericForeignKey in query filters ; 2) a GenericForeignKey won't appear in a ModelForm" (from [GenericForeignKey or ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538041/genericforeignkey-or-foreignkey)).

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to add choices to the BaseModel to have a string representation of your boolean value. If you set the strings equal to the A and B model names, you can use the [model.get_foo_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method to return the name of the model. Then use the Python `getattr()` method to access attributes as variables.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    base_model_choices = (
        (True, 'A'),
        (False, 'B'),
    )

    is_a = models.BooleanField(choices=base_model_choices)
```

For example,

```
base = BaseModel.objects.get(id=1)
queryset = base.getattr(models, get_is_a_display()).all()
obj = getattr(models, get_is_a_display()).objects.create(base=base)
```

Comment: interesting idea, thanks! I'll test it.