# django how to set relation to some fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

i want to set relation in that case

```
class SaleType(models.Model):
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contract = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price)

class SaleType2(models.Model):
    totalContract = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    requierd = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.totalContract)

class ForSale(models.Model):
    method = models.ForeignKey(Method, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.method)
```

if method in ForSale = Cash get foreign key for SaleType

if method in ForSale = Rent get foreign key for SaleType2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `GenericForeignKey` is what you are looking for. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey).

```py
class ForSale(models.Model):
    method = models.CharField(choices=(('Cash', 'cash'), ('Rent', 'rent')), ...)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...
```

Add validations to support `content_type` limited to `SaleType` & `SaleType2`. Also maintain the relation in each row between `method` and `content_type`.

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907211/genericforeignkey-and-admin-in-django) might help